Issue with creating CloudSolrClient instance in Solr 9 along setting 'ConnectionTimeout' and 'SocketTimeout' properties
In SolrJ 8 we are creating  org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient instance  by setting properties ConnectionTimeout and SocketTimeout
 CloudSolrClient.Builder builder = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(zkServers, Optional.ofNullable(zooKeeperChRoot))
                .withConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeoutMilli)
                .withSocketTimeout(socketTimeoutMilli);

In SolrJ 9, I do not find option to set ConnectionTimeout and SocketTimeout.
I tried something as below.
But I could not find option to construct Http2SolrClient  by passing HttpClient.
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                            .setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeoutMilli) // Set connection timeout in milliseconds
                            .setSocketTimeout(socketTimeoutMilli)
                            .build())
                    .build(); 
Http2SolrClient http2SolrClient = null;
CloudSolrClient  cloudSolrClient  = builder.withHttpClient(http2SolrClient).build();

